# Making pixels semi-transparent

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to make some pixels semi-transparent.

Using a QPainter with pen color Qt::color0 and Qt::color1 works to make pixels fully transparent or opaque, but I tried to set the pen color to 0.5 to make a partially transparent pixel, but it does not work as I would expect.

In this example, the opaque pixels are red, the transparent pixels are white (the color of the background, and I would expect the semitransparent pixels to be pink, but they are also white:

http://programmingexamples.net/index.php?title=Qt/Images/SemiTransparentPixels

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: In your code, the line `painter.setPen(.5);` is probably not doing what you expect it to do. You need to do something like `painter.setPen( QColor( 255, 0, 0, 127 ) );` like Stephen Chu suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set alpha to 0.5 (127) in your QColor: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#QColor-2

Comment: Hm even with painter.setPen( QColor( 255, 0, 0, 127 ) ); as Tim Meyer suggested, the top right corner (with alpha=127) is red rather than pink. Does the transparency only work for other objects and not the background?

Comment: I also don't understand the difference between setAlphaChannel and setMask?

Comment: You are using a QBitmap as the painter backstore. Bitmap is only black and white or completely opaque or transparent. It doesn't know anything in between. Use a QPixmap or QImage for the painter backstore.

Comment: I think we're getting closer... See http://programmingexamples.net/index.php?title=Qt/Images/SemiTransparentPixels#form.cpp - I am now using a QPixmap for the backstore. The code there now produces a fully semi-transparent square, where I am expecting to see the 4 quadrants that I defined. I am starting with a QPixmap and then trying to only alter it's alpha channel - do I have to re-set the first 3 channels to the existing value of the original pixmap? The reason I started with a QBitmap is that I thought I was only setting up one channel to pass to setAlphaChannel rather than a full image?

Comment: setAlphaChennel method is now obsolete. You will have to changed the alpha value of each pixel data in your image. For that, use QImage and modify the underlying raw pixel data.

Comment: Awesome, I see. Got it working here: http://programmingexamples.net/index.php?title=Qt/Images/SemiTransparentPixels#form.cpp